# Programmatically switch between Tabs in a TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have tabbed page with 4 children(4 tabs), and i want to override back button to allways set first 1 page when you push it. I tried several ways, this seems to make the most sense to me, but it doesn't work - tabbedPage is always null (when i override in all tabs)

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var tabbedPage = this.Parent as TabbedPage;
    tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[1];
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

I tried to override this back button in TabbedPage Parent like this:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if(CurrentPage == FirstPage)
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }
    CurrentPage = FirstPage;
    return true;
}
```

but it always close my app. Any idea why that tabbedPage is null for me?

Comment: Likely it's because `this.Parent` cannot be cast as a `TabbedPage`. When using `as` a failed cast returns `null` rather than throwing an exception. Debug it and see what `this.Parent` actually is.

Comment: Yes of course i cannot cast as a `TabbedPage`. I have to do`'this.Parent.Parent` and it's casting how it should be. The problem was that my Children is NavigationPage, and that's why i can't cast it. Thank you!

Comment: Does it work now ? You could check my answer .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem was that my children page is `NavigationPage` and I should use `this.Parent.Parent` to cast. So this is how it should be done when u use `NavigaionPage` as `Children` of `TabbedPage`

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;
    tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[0];
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you have TabbedPage, `OnBackButtonPressed` is being invoked not in the ContentPage, but instead on the TabbedPage itself. So, the correct place to override the method is in the TabbedPage indeed.

Secondly, if you override the method in the TabbedPage itself, it will do the work, like this:

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    var firstPage = Children[0];
    if (CurrentPage == firstPage)
    {
        return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
    }

    CurrentPage = firstPage;
    return true;
}
```

NB: Be careful what your `Children` collection is. If you have wrapped your pages in a `NavigationPage`, the check won't be correct.

Comment: It is being invoked in ContentPage too. My problem was that my children page is NavigationPage and I should use 'this.Parent.Parent' to cast.
  
`protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
  {
   var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;
   tabbedPage.CurrentPage = tabbedPage.Children[0];
   return true;
  }`

Answer (score 1):

You could set the current TabbedPage in **App.xaml.cs** when set the **MainPage** of App .

#### in App.xaml.cs

MainPage  here is the TabbedPage in your project.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public MainPage CurrentPage { get; }
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage tabbedPage = new MainPage();
        CurrentPage = tabbedPage;

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        MainPage = tabbedPage;
    }
    //...
}
```

And now you can access it in child page .

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{

    App currentApp = Application.Current as App;
    var tabbedpage = currentApp.CurrentPage;

    tabbedpage.CurrentPage = tabbedpage.Children[0];

    return true;

}
```

The above code works fine in my project. If it still doesn't work on your side, you could share a sample so that I can test it .

Comment: Yes your code will work fine in simple tabbedpage but when i post this question i wasn't aware that this problem is related to my children are NavigationPage and to test your code and to test your code I would have to change a lot. Thank's anyway

Comment: You could share your answer or accept the answer if it helps you :)